# How to restore a missing language icon in the taskbar in windows 8.1 without restarting PC?

Tags: windows-8.1

I can't see my language bar and can't restore it. It usually returns after restart. Can I do this without a restart? I suppose I killed some app in the task manager. Don't remember what exactly. I think there must be a way to relaunch from cmd prompt. Not sure. I've used some tutorials from youtube, but they didn't work.
Would like to know more about it. Can't switch languages now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following ways:

**Way 1**

Open the **Control Panel**.

open **Region** and click on **Language preferences**.

Click on **Add a language**.

You can select and add the language in the next screen. Once you have added more than one language, you will see the language bar on Windows 8.1 notification area.

View if the language bar is in the taskbar.

**Way 2**

Open "registry".

Navigate to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run** ,
right click on blank space on right side, select **New String Value**.

Again right click on the newly created value and select **modify**, then type **“ctfmon”=”CTFMON.EXE”** in **Value data**.

Press OK and restart your computer.

View if the language bar is in the taskbar.

**Note:** Remember to take a backup of registry before modifying if you are not comfortable with play around in registry, because wrong modification can cause issue to Windows OS.

Source: [Windows 8, 8.1 and Windows 7 Language Bar Missing, How to Get It Back](http://www.sysprobs.com/language-bar-missing-vista-windows-7)

**Way 3**

a. Click on the **arrow** in notification area and click on **customize**.

b. Click on **Turn system icons on or off**.

c. Enable **Input indicator** and click on **OK**.

d. View if the language bar is in the taskbar.

Source: [How to restore missing language bar in Windows 8.1](https://lendy007.wordpress.com/2015/05/13/how-to-restore-missing-language-bar-in-windows-8-1/)